# AVPlayer frame animation

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

I am developing an application that include functionality to play video with per-frame animation.
You can see an [example](https://youtu.be/5AkdaXqfqdA?t=1m) of such functionality.

I already tried to add `CAKeyFrameAnimation` to sublayer of `AVSynchronizedLayer` and have [some troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118759/avplayer-and-avsynchronizedlayer-fps-issue) with it.

I also already tried to pre-render video with `AVAssetExportSession`, and it is working perfectly. But it's very slow. It needa up to 3 minutes to render such video.

Maybe there are other approaches to make it?

**Update:**

This is how I implement animation with `AVSynchronizedLayer`:

```
let fullScreenAnimationLayer = CALayer()
fullScreenAnimationLayer.frame = videoRect
fullScreenAnimationLayer.geometryFlipped = true

values: [NSValue] = [], times: [NSNumber] = []

// fill values array with positions of face center for each frame
values.append(NSValue(CATransform3D: t))

// fill times with corresoinding time for each frame
times.append(NSNumber(double: (Double(j) / fps) / videoDuration)) // where fps = 25 (according to video file fps)

...

let transform = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
transform.duration = videoDuration
transform.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete
transform.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
transform.values = values
transform.keyTimes = times
transform.removedOnCompletion = false
transform.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
fullScreenAnimationLayer.addAnimation(transform, forKey: "a_transform")

...

if let syncLayer = AVSynchronizedLayer(playerItem: player.currentItem) {
    syncLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: videoView.bounds.size)
    syncLayer.addSublayer(fullScreenAnimationLayer)
    videoView.layer.addSublayer(syncLayer)
}
```

Comment: Shot in the dark: did you try changing the calculation mode to a linear calculation? Perhaps linear interpolation would offset the difference in frame rates.

Comment: @TheLivingForce, yes, I already try all types of predefined modes (just in case). I'm tried different predefined types of calculation functions and implement few custom. Code above produce best result.

Comment: Have you tried using the `customVideoCompositor` on your `AVPlayerItem`?

Comment: change `values: [NSValue]` to `values: [Any]`.

Comment: Also set the `zIndex` of the `syncLayer` to a high value.

Comment: @PranavKasetti the code above is from earlier versions of Swift (1 or 2nd, don't recall). also, zIndex didn't really change anything. the visual part (e.g. position/relations) is fine, the problem was with the smoothness. didn't found a proper solution though

Comment: @rkyr did you solved the issue? I've tried CAKeyframeAnimation with AVSynchronizedLayer. And it worked for me. If you need help let me know.

Comment: @rkyr one more thing, in case you got the solution, can you share the major obstacle you've faced.

Answer (score 0):

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player: AVPlayer?
    var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
    var animationImageView: UIImageView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path_to_your_video_file")
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        player?.play()

        // Create an image view for per-frame animation
        animationImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        animationImageView?.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "frame1")!, UIImage(named: "frame2")!, UIImage(named: "frame3")!]
        animationImageView?.animationDuration = 1.0 // Adjust as needed
        animationImageView?.startAnimating()

        view.addSubview(animationImageView!)

        // Start CADisplayLink
        displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(update))
        displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .default)
    }

    @objc func update() {
        // Update animation position or any other logic here
        // For example, you could sync the animation with the video playback time
        guard let currentTime = player?.currentTime().seconds else { return }
        // Update animation based on currentTime
    }
}
```

Replace "frame1", "frame2", "frame3", etc. with the names of your animation frames. Adjust the animation duration and any other parameters as needed.

Answer (score -2):

Here's my opinion,

add AVPlayer layer property(AVPlayerLayer class) to a sublayer to a UIView layer, then manipulate the view animation.

for example,

```
AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:blahURL options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:urlAsset];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
playerLayer.frame = yourFrame;

UIView *videoView = [UIView new];
[videoView addSublayer:playerLayer];
```

then

give animations to videoView